# Copy static values from one class to another in php

Tags: php, class, static, copy

I'm trying to copy values from a static array to another class parameter. So, I don't know it is possible or I am just dealing with a simple mistake.

```
class EstadosConstantes
{
    const NO_APLICA = 0;
    const LIBRE = 1;

    public static $celdas = array(
        self::LIBRE => array(
            'id' => self::LIBRE , 
            "estilo" => "libre"
        ), 
        self::NO_APLICA => array(
            'id' => self::NO_APLICA, 
            "estilo" => "no-aplica"
        ),
    );
}
```

This is the another class:

```
class Reservacion
{

     public static $estados = array(
        \models\EstadosConstantes::LIBRE => \models\EstadosConstantes::$celdas[\models\EstadosConstantes::LIBRE],
    );
```

As you note above, I want to copy the LIBRE array from `EstadosConstantes` to `Reservacion` class, but if I try that option I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in /models/Reservacion.php on line 22

Where `line 22` is:

```
\models\EstadosConstantes::LIBRE => \models\EstadosConstantes::$celdas[\models\EstadosConstantes::LIBRE],
```

I just one to centralize all the possible values in `EstadosConstantes`, and then, each class could copy the values requiered.

Comment: Hmm, form what I understand isn't it easier to make global variables for the values you need. Or a global array if possible?

Comment: The bad thing here is that `\models\EstadosConstantes` must keep that array, becasue the project was develpment with this structure. I am another coder of the project

Comment: Hmm, did you try to make your const static too?

Comment: And even better, can't you just derive from `EstadosConstantes`?

Comment: @Leron, sorry for delay, my internet connection went away. But, you give me a good idea.. How about convert `EstadosConstantes` to an interface?

Comment: Yes, `Interfaces` is perfect place for constants especially if they are gonna be used in many classes

Comment: @Leron, I got another obstacle: intefaces can not holds arrays! :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm just talking here. Can't give you working answer, but then you still can try at least abstract if this works for you or plain class if nothing else, but if the below answer works for you why you seek another solution?

Comment: @Leron, I think that I explain myself incorrectly: I was trying to improve the answer below , but it does not work too. I am no trying to find another solution. However, you can see my final answer above :)

Comment: not sure what you meant by `I just one to centralize all the possible values` but good for you that you solve the problem! Cheers!

Comment: @Leron, I do not have a lot of skills to explain it how I do like, and the things get worst because I come from Java, so the logic of a programming language change a little bit, not all things can be implemented identically :p  Well.. thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

Thus, you can't do that, since `EstadosConstantes::$celdas` is a variable

Alternatively, as Michel Feldheim suggested in a comment, you can initialise it in a constructor, but it will be available only after you create an instance

```
class Reservacion
{
    public static $estados;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$estados = array(EstadosConstantes::LIBRE => EstadosConstantes::$celdas[EstadosConstantes::LIBRE]);
    }
}

$reservacion = new Reservacion();

var_dump(Reservacion::$estados);
```

Comment: @Manix You can do it in the class constructor

Comment: doesn't have to be the constructor - can be any function e.g. `public static function init()` which, depending on how the class is used, may be more appropriate.

Comment: @AD7six, that is a good alternative! I will combine this answer with yours.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

This is how I make it works: Just keep the references, not the entire array:

```
class Reservacion
{

     public static $estados = array(
        \models\EstadosConstantes::LIBRE
    );
```

Then, if a want a specific value I can do something like this:

```
$estilo = models\EstadosConstantes::$celdas[models\Reservacion::$estados[\models\EstadosConstantes::LIBRE]]['estilo'];
```